# Undefined Index PHP Line 12

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Trying to upload a paper via php. It just gets stored on my local drive. I keep getting undefined index on line 12. Not sure why, I swear it was working before. What can I do to fix this? Please help.

```
<?php
require_once("constants.php"); //Now constants will be accessible

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
if (!$link) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}
//Use array to not repeat code
$post_vars = array('paper', 'author1', 'author2', 'author3', 'university', 'contact', 'file');
foreach($post_vars as $key) {
     $$key = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST[$key]);
    //For example now there is a variable $firstname that you can use
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO papers (paper, author1, author2, author3, university, contact, file) VALUES ('$paper', '$author1', '$author2', '$author3', '$university', '$contact', '$file');";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
mysqli_close($link);

 if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){
    $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];  
    $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
    if(isset($name)){
        if(!empty($name)){      
            $location = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/Proj-1-1/uploads/';      
            if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
                echo 'uploaded';
            }
        }       
    }  else {
        echo 'please uploaded';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

your parameters are not necessarily in the `$_POST` array

```
foreach($post_vars as $key) {
    if (isset($_POST[$key])){
        $$key = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST[$key]);
        //For example now there is a variable $firstname that you can use
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Have a look at this:

```
$name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];
if(isset($name))
```

The variable `$name` is defined, you don't need to check `isset($name)` since you've defined it in the previous line (`$name = ...`). You can just check if it's not `null`

Notice that in the line `$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];` you don't really know if `$_FILES` has the `file` index and if `$_FILES['file']` has the `name` index.

You can verify it:

```
$name = isset($_FILES['file']) && isset($_FILES['file']['name']) ? $_FILES['file']['name'] : '';
```

Comment: What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Getting this error now: 

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj-1\actions\paper.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj-1\actions\paper.php on line 23
please uploaded

Comment: look, you have: `$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];` and after that `if(isset($name)){` . Now, `$name` definitely has a value, can be `null`, but still has a value. Your `isset` should be on `$_FILES['file']['name']`

Comment: Can you please expand your answer above with another block of code to show what you mean?

Comment: no more errors, but I don't see my file still being uploaded.

Comment: The file not being uploaded - try the suggestions _while_ tailing the error log and let us know what do you see?